# Thymeleaf + springboot not working together

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to use springboot with thymeleaf. I created a controller, which looks like this:

I have the project struct like this:

```
package com.mbtimeet.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String index(){
    return "index";
}
}
```

And I have an index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th=“http://www.thymeleaf.org”         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
</head>
<body>
Hi there.
</body>
</html>
```

And it's just not working. after I open the "http://localhost:8080/hello" page I get an exception.

LOG: http://pastebin.com/MLPgpqph

Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'mbti-meet'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

ERROR:

```
2016-10-18 22:58:15.413 ERROR 4896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="index", line 2 - column 16] with root cause
```

I followed a tutorial, the only difference was that the user used maven.

Comment: Please copy errors in your post; just the errors not the entire log.

Answer (score 2):

The log message tells you exactly the issue. For some reason when you created the index.html file the `xmlns:th=“http://www.thymeleaf.org”` got the UTF-8 formatted quotes instead of the ascii ones `"`. As such Thymeleaf is having issues parsing the file. Update the attribute to be `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

Comment: I got the same error, and I solved adding xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org as @ShawClark suggested, and I remeoved the tag    <meta charset="UTF-8">